# TypeError: Immutable variables cannot have a non-value type

Tags: solidity

Why i am unable to set a string as immutable in solidity??

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract myContract {
    string public immutable myName = "Dude";
    // TypeError: Immutable variables cannot have a non-value type.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it is not yet supported, from the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/contracts.html?highlight=immutable#constant-and-immutable-state-variables) :

> Not all types for constants and immutables are implemented at this
> time. The only supported types are strings (only for constants) and
> value types.

In the meantime, you can use a `constant` variable, with the drawback that its value must be defined at compilation time. But given your example, that should be enough :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract myContract {
    string public constant myName = "Dude";
}
```